# How to start xde.exe using cmd and pass vm_name as a parameter to the command?

Tags: windows-phone, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I start xde.exe ( windows phone emulator ) using the following command " AnycpuStart xde.exe ". But it starts the emulator with default name " Default windows phone emulator". But I wish to start a different emulator, Say " Lumia 720 ". How will I pass the virtual machine name (vm_name is found from hyper v manager) as a parameter to the command. Like " AnyCpuStart xde.exe Lumia 720". 
Below image might help. It is a help window that pops up when i type the command.
Or please tell me how to start a virtual machine listed in Hyper-V manager using cmd.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution.

Got to CMD 
Change directory (cd)  to path of xde.exe 
Pass name parameter in this format : " xde.exe -name vm_name "
The virtual machine name should not have spaces. 
Virtual machine names can be found in hyper-v manager.